# Not able to receive test email from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am personalising an email template in Marketing Cloud with ampScript, pulling data from multiple Data Extensions. However, when I tried to send it out as a test email, I am not receiving it at all.

There are no visible errors in the email format, code or data extensions. As u can see in the screenshot below, there are 0 emails sent out.

I even tried it with a simple email without any codes.

Appreciate if someone could advise on this.

[image: Test Email Tracking]

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons, below are most common reasons

- The subscriber is '**Unsubscribed**' in All Subscriber list.
- Make sure the field used to store EmailAddress in your Target Data Extension, is used with the **DataType** as 'EmailAddress'

  *Also Advised use only one field with the DataType as 'EmailAddress'*